# Azure Automation Variables

Tags: azure, variables, automation, azure-runbook, azure-service-principal

I am trying to make a code using PowerShell so that secrets are not hardcoded on my runbook so that it will not be exposed in the script. I created encrypted variables in my automation account. These variables are AppID, AppSecret and TenantID.

This is the part of the script to login automatically to Azure. I didn't use managed identity for some compatibility reasons with the script.

My script is running fine when secrets and IDs are hardcoded but when I created variables it  is not working. Error message is "Run Connect-AzAccount". Below is my code. Need help on how to correct this. Thank you in advance.

```
$AzVariableApplicationID = 'AppID'
$AzVariableAppSecret = 'AppSecret'
$AzVariableTenantID = 'TenantID'

$AppID = Get-AzAutomationVariable -Name $AzVariableApplicationID
$AppSecret = Get-AzAutomationVariable -Name $AzVariableAppSecret
$TenantID = Get-AzAutomationVariable -Name $AzVariableTenantID

$SecureSecret = $AppSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $AppID, $SecureSecret

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantID
```

Comment: Have you created "azure run as account" under automation accounts?

Comment: I didn't create "azure run as account" as it will be retired soon as per microsoft. I came up with the below code and it is working now.




**$AppID = Get-AutomationVariable -Name AppID
$TenantID = Get-AutomationVariable -Name TenantID
$AppSecret = Get-AutomationVariable -Name AppSecret

$SecureSecret = $AppSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $AppID, $SecureSecret

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantID**

Answer (score 0):

> [As described in PsCustom Object - Hitchikers GUID(e) to Automation](https://pscustomobject.github.io/powershell/azure/Azure-Automation-Variables/#:%7E:text=As%20I%20mentioned%20it%20is%20not%20possible%20to,a%20small%20script%20that%20will%20show%20this%20behaviour)
> , It is not possible to retrieve values for encrypted variables as they’re available within the runbook at runtime via the **Get-AutomationVariable** cmdlet

I found an alternative approach to *"Connect Azure"* by using "*Certificate-based authentication*" inside PowerShell runbook without *hardcoding* the values:

- ***Created a new Service principal and provided the "Owner" role access to avoid any restrictions***.
  [image]
- ***To authenticate via service principal, I create a new self-signed certificate with the command***:

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=xxxxxCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
```

- ***Upload a certificate under `Certifications & Secrets`***:

  1. Click `windows + R` to open the run box and give `certmgr.msc` as shown here.

  [image]

  2. Export a certificate without private key.
     [image]
- Upload a certificate in the below path:
  `AzureAD -> App registrations -> Serviceprincipal`

[image]

- Now, I have exported the same certificate with `key` and uploaded inside my automation account to authenticate Service principal connection:

[image]

- Added an "Azure Service Principal" connection inside automation accounts by providing *"ApplicationID, TenantID, Certificate Thumbprint"* of my Service principal as shown:

[image]

- Inside PowerShell runbook, I ran the below script that works for me:

```
  $connectionName = "serviceprincipalname"
  try
  {
     $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
    "Logging in to Azure..."
     Add-AzureRMAccount  
     -ServicePrincipal `
     -TenantID $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID ` 
     -ApplicationID $servicePrincipalConnection.applicationID  `
     -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
}
catch {
  if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
  {
     $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found. "
     throw  $ErrorMessage
  }  else{
       Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
       throw  $_.Exception
     }
}
```

[image]

***Logged in to Azure***:

[image]

[Register an App in App registrations and create a service principal in AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal)